# iOS Google Maps home location button not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS for Map integration in an app, I want to show the home location button on the map. I have used

```
_mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

The button is visible in 4 inch screen devices but not in 3.5 inch screen. What should I do to make it visible in 3.5 inch devices also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that your map view is sized to fit a 4" device, and so on a 3.5" device the bottom part of the map view is not visible, which includes the my location button, and possibly also the Google logo.

If that's the case, then you'll need to adjust the size of your map view to fit the size of the device.